# How to search for contacts using zoomInfo API

Tags: python, string

I am working on a web scraping project for collecting information about employees using their first and last name. I'd like to leverage the zoomInfo api to accomplish this.

I've reviewed the documentation here:https://api-docs.zoominfo.com/#7bad886b-b4a8-46cd-9a55-1725944f2cc2.

My current implementation returns a valid jwt, but I do not know how to modify the payload to perform the contact search.

```
import zi_api_auth_client
import requests

jwt_token = zi_api_auth_client.user_name_pwd_authentication("evan.gertis@netfoundry.io", "!z1UuiH^8920EaCEbX")

url = "https://api.zoominfo.com/lookup/inputfields/contact/search"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer '+jwt_token
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

This returns

```
[{"fieldName":"personId","fieldType":"String","description":"Unique ZoomInfo identifier for the contact. Can include a comma-separated list."},{"fieldName":"emailAddress","fieldType":"String","description":"Work email address for the contact in example@example.com format"},{"fieldName":"hashedEmail","fieldType":"String","description":"Hashed email value for the contact. Allows searching via an email address with the extra security of not exposing the email. Supported hash algorithms are: MD5, SHA1, SHA256 and SHA512."},{"fieldName":"fullName","fieldType":"String","description":"Contact full name"},{"fieldName":"firstName","fieldType":"String","description":"Contact first name"},{"fieldName":"middleInitial","fieldType":"String","description":"Contact middle initial"},{"fieldName":"lastName","fieldType":"String","description":"Contact last name"},{"fieldName":"jobTitle","fieldType":"String","description":"Contact title at current place of employment. Use OR to input multiple job titles."},{"fieldName":"excludeJobTitle","fieldType":"String","description":"Exclude comma-separated list of job titles"},{"fieldName":"managementLevel","fieldType":"String","description":"Contact management level at current place of employment"},{"fieldName":"excludeManagementLevel","fieldType":"String","description":"Exclude comma separated list of management levels"},{"fieldName":"department","fieldType":"String","description":"Contact department at current place of employment"},{"fieldName":"boardMember","fieldType":"String","description":"Exclude or include board members from search results"},{"fieldName":"excludePartialProfiles","fieldType":"Boolean","description":"Contacts who do not have an active company associated with them are considered partial profiles. Exclude contacts with a partial profile from search results."},{"fieldName":"executivesOnly","fieldType":"Boolean","description":"Return only executives"},{"fieldName":"requiredFields","fieldType":"String","description":"Specify a list of required fields for each record returned. Can include email, phone, personalEmail, and mobilePhone. Can include a comma-separated list of these fields."},{"fieldName":"contactAccuracyScoreMin","fieldType":"String","description":"Minimum accuracy score for search results. This score indicates the likelihood that a contact is reachable and still employed by the company listed. Minimum score is 70 and maximum is 99."},{"fieldName":"contactAccuracyScoreMax","fieldType":"String","description":"Maximum accuracy score for search results. This score indicates the likelihood that a contact is reachable and still employed by the company listed. Minimum score is 70 and maximum is 99."},{"fieldName":"jobFunction","fieldType":"String","description":"Contact job function at their current place of employment"},{"fieldName":"lastUpdatedInMonths","fieldType":"Integer","description":"Number of months within which the contact's profile was last updated"},{"fieldName":"hasBeenNotified","fieldType":"String","description":"Contacts who have been notified of inclusion in ZoomInfo's database. Values are exclude, include, and only"},{"fieldName":"companyPastOrPresent","fieldType":"String","description":"Returns companies based on a contact's work history. Values are present (default), past, and pastAndPresent"},{"fieldName":"school","fieldType":"String","description":"Searches by contact's education"},{"fieldName":"degree","fieldType":"String","description":"Searches by contact's education"},{"fieldName":"locationCompanyId","fieldType":"ArrayList","description":"Searches by contact's locationIds"},{"fieldName":"companyId","fieldType":"String","description":"ZoomInfo unique identifier for the company. Will accept a comma-separated list."},{"fieldName":"companyName","fieldType":"String","description":"Company name"},{"fieldName":"companyWebsite","fieldType":"String","description":"Company domain"},{"fieldName":"companyTicker","fieldType":"ArrayList","description":"Company stock ticker symbol"},{"fieldName":"companyDescription","fieldType":"String","description":"Text description unique to the company you want to use as search criteria"},{"fieldName":"parentId","fieldType":"String","description":"ZoomInfo Company ID for parent company"},{"fieldName":"ultimateParentId","fieldType":"String","description":"ZoomInfo Company ID for ultimate parent company"},{"fieldName":"companyType","fieldType":"String","description":"Company type (private, public, and so on)"},{"fieldName":"address","fieldType":"String","description":"Company address"},{"fieldName":"street","fieldType":"String","description":"Company street"},{"fieldName":"state","fieldType":"String","description":"Company state"},{"fieldName":"zipCode","fieldType":"String","description":"Zip Code of the company's primary address"},{"fieldName":"country","fieldType":"String","description":"Company country"},{"fieldName":"continent","fieldType":"String","description":"Company continent"},{"fieldName":"zipCodeRadiusMiles","fieldType":"String","description":"Used in conjunction with zipCode, designates a geographical radius (in miles) from the zipCode provided."},{"fieldName":"hashTagString","fieldType":"String","description":"Hash tags for a company. Can include a comma-separated list."},{"fieldName":"techAttributeTagList","fieldType":"String","description":"Specify technology product tags"},{"fieldName":"subUnitTypes","fieldType":"String","description":"Company sub types (e.g., division, subsidiary and so on)."},{"fieldName":"primaryIndustriesOnly","fieldType":"Boolean","description":"Used in conjunction with the industryCodes input parameter. When set to true, any result returned must have one of the specified industries in the top two. If no industries are specified, then this parameter will be ignored. Default is false."},{"fieldName":"industryCodes","fieldType":"String","description":"Top-level industry that the contact works in. A contact can have multiple top level industries. Tags are based on the contact's current company. Can include a comma-separated list."},{"fieldName":"industryKeywords","fieldType":"String","description":"Industry keywords associated with a company. Can include a comma-separated list."},{"fieldName":"sicCodes","fieldType":"String","description":"Four-digit numerical codes assigned by the U.S. government to business establishments to identify the primary business of the establishment."},{"fieldName":"naicsCodes","fieldType":"String","description":"Four-digit numerical codes assigned by the U.S. government to business establishments to identify the primary business of the establishment. "},{"fieldName":"revenueMin","fieldType":"Integer","description":"Minimum annual revenue for a company in U.S. dollars. Use with revenueMax to set a range. Alternatively, you can use the revenue parameter to search for pre-defined ranges."},{"fieldName":"revenueMax","fieldType":"Integer","description":"Maximum annual revenue for a company in U.S. dollars. Use with revenueMin to set a range. Alternatively, you can use the revenue parameter to search for pre-defined ranges."},{"fieldName":"revenue","fieldType":"String","description":"Annual revenue range in U.S. dollars. Accepts a comma-separated list of values. Alternatively, to get more granular ranges, you can use the revenueMin and revenueMax parameters."},{"fieldName":"employeeRangeMin","fieldType":"String","description":"Minimum employee count for a company. Use with employeeRangeMax to set a range. Alternatively, you can use the employeeCount parameter to search for pre-defined ranges."},{"fieldName":"employeeRangeMax","fieldType":"String","description":"Maximum employee count for a company. Use with employeeRangeMin to set a range. Alternatively, you can use the employeeCount parameter to search for pre-defined ranges."},{"fieldName":"employeeCount","fieldType":"String","description":"Employee count range. Accepts a comma-separated list of values. Alternatively, to get more granular ranges, you can use the employeeRangeMin and employeeRangeMax parameters."},{"fieldName":"companyRanking","fieldType":"String","description":"Company ranking list (e.g., Fortune 500 and so on)"},{"fieldName":"metroRegion","fieldType":"String","description":"Company metro area. Accepts a comma-separated list of U.S. and Canada metro areas."},{"fieldName":"locationSearchType","fieldType":"String","description":"Location type (PersonOrHQ, PersonAndHQ, Person, HQ, PersonThenHQ)."},{"fieldName":"fundingAmountMin","fieldType":"Integer","description":"Minimum funding amount in thousands (e.g., 1 = 1000, 500 = 500,000). If fundingAmountMin is used without fundingAmountMax, the result will be the amount specified or greater."},{"fieldName":"fundingAmountMax","fieldType":"Integer","description":"Maximum funding amount in thousands (e.g., 1 = 1000, 500 = 500,000). If fundingAmountMax is used without fundingAmountMin, the result will be the amount specified or less."},{"fieldName":"fundingStartDate","fieldType":"String","description":"Start date of the funding in YYYY-MM-DD format. If fundingStartDate and fundingEndDate are both specified, they will be used as a range. Start date after end date returns an error. If start date and end date are the same, will return results for exact date."},{"fieldName":"fundingEndDate","fieldType":"String","description":"End date of the funding in YYYY-MM-DD format. If fundingStartDate and fundingEndDate are both specified, they will be used as a range. Start date after end date returns an error. If start date and end date are the same, will return results for exact date."},{"fieldName":"excludedRegions","fieldType":"String","description":"Exclude a company metro area. Accepts a comma-separated list of U.S. and Canada metro areas."},{"fieldName":"zoominfoContactsMin","fieldType":"String","description":"Minimum number of ZoomInfo contacts associated with company"},{"fieldName":"zoominfoContactsMax","fieldType":"String","description":"Maximum number of ZoomInfo contacts associated with company"},{"fieldName":"companyStructureIncludedSubUnitTypes","fieldType":"String","description":"Company hierarchical structure"},{"fieldName":"oneYearEmployeeGrowthRateMin","fieldType":"String","description":"Minimum one year employee growth rate for a company. Use with oneYearEmployeeGrowthRateMax to set a range."},{"fieldName":"oneYearEmployeeGrowthRateMax","fieldType":"String","description":"Maximum one year employee growth rate for a company. Use with oneYearEmployeeGrowthRateMin to set a range."},{"fieldName":"twoYearEmployeeGrowthRateMin","fieldType":"String","description":"Minimum two year employee growth rate for a company. Use with twoYearEmployeeGrowthRateMax to set a range."},{"fieldName":"twoYearEmployeeGrowthRateMax","fieldType":"String","description":"Maximum two year employee growth rate for a company. Use with twoYearEmployeeGrowthRateMin to set a range."},{"fieldName":"lastUpdatedDateAfter","fieldType":"String","description":"The date after which the contact's profile was last updated"},{"fieldName":"validDateAfter","fieldType":"String","description":"The date after which the contact's profile was last validated"},{"fieldName":"phone","fieldType":"ArrayList","description":"List of person phones or mobile numbers"},{"fieldName":"positionStartDateMin","fieldType":"String","description":"Minimum date for when a contact began current employment. Use with positionStartDateMax to set a range"},{"fieldName":"positionStartDateMax","fieldType":"String","description":"Maximum date for when a contact began current employment. Use with positionStartDateMin to set a range"},{"fieldName":"supplementalEmail","fieldType":"ArrayList","description":"Supplemental email address for the contact in example@example.com format"},{"fieldName":"rpp","fieldType":"Integer","description":"Limits the results returned to the given number of results per page"},{"fieldName":"page","fieldType":"Integer","description":"Provides the results for the given page, used in conjunction with rpp"},{"fieldName":"sortBy","fieldType":"String","description":"Sorts results by valid output fields"},{"fieldName":"sortOrder","fieldType":"String","description":"Default value is desc. It accepts the following values { Asc, Ascending, desc, descending }"}]
```

If anyone can tell me how to update the payload I'd like to make a request like so

```
payload = {"contact": "John Doe"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to change your input to a POST request:

"POST Contact Search
https://api.zoominfo.com/search/contact
Returns a list of Contacts from ZoomInfo's data that meet the specified search criteria.
Input parameters may require specific values, some of which are too extensive to list in the parameter descriptions. You can retrieve these values using the Lookup endpoints."

vs the GET request:

"GET Contact Search Outputs
https://api.zoominfo.com/lookup/outputfields/contact/search
Returns a list of fields included in the response for the Contact Search endpoint."

So from what I can see- the GET search only returns info about the input fields while the POST search generates unique info for each field based on input params.
let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use enrichment functionality :

```
var zoompayload = {
    "matchPersonInput": [
      {
        "firstName": fname,
        "lastName": lname,
        "companyName": cname,
        // "companyId": 358636815,
        //"emailAddress":"forabc@rediffmail.com"
        "emailAddress": email
      }
    ],
    "outputFields": outfields
  };

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    redirect: 'follow',
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer " + "your jwt here" },
    'payload': JSON.stringify(zoompayload),
  };

  // Fetch all the required fields
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.zoominfo.com/enrich/contact", options);
```

Try this and refer their [api doc](https://api-docs.zoominfo.com/)